# Get post from custom post type order by two taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

In woocommerce i want product by brand (ORDER BY A-Z) with specific custom taxonomy. I have two taxonomies product_cat and product_brand. I did some code to reach my goals but the problem is i have to call WP_Query again and again. The code which i tried:-

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'           => 'name', 
    'order'             => 'ASC'
    );
    $terms_brand=get_terms('product_brand',$args);
    foreach($terms_brand as $term_b){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $term->term_id,
            )

        ),
        'product_brand' => $term_b->slug
    );
    $query=query_posts($args);
    while(have_posts()){
    the_post();
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_brand' );
    echo the_title_attribute().' --- '.$terms[0]->name.'<br/>';

    }
}
```

How could i make it possible not to run `WP_Query` continuously.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, syntax is just slightly off. I can't quite work out how/what terms you need to query for, but this should be the structure of your arguments:

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby'   => 'name',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $ids_of_product_cat_terms,
            ),

            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_brand',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $ids_of_product_brand_terms,
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

Read up on [tax queries from the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Comment: thanks for your answer. But this doesn't produce a desirable result because its order product by name instead of order by product by brand name.